# Using Native Fetch With Proxy in Node.js doesn't change my IP

Tags: node.js, proxy, fetch-api, https-proxy-agent

I've upgraded my Node.js to the latest version which supports fetch natively. I'm trying to use a free public proxy to test, however when I'm making a request, it still comes from me directly. I know that because I'm calling an "Get my IP" service, and it returns my hope IP.

Here's the code example:

```
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

fetch(`https://api.ipify.org?format=json`, {agent: new HttpsProxyAgent("36.32.21.45:8085")})
.then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Tried putting proxy settings in the header as well this way:

```
const proxyAgent = require("proxy-agent");

(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', {
      headers: {
        agent: new proxyAgent('http://80.48.119.28:8080'),
      }
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data); //it shows my ip
})();
```

What am I missing?